# With python: intervals at x:00 repeat

Tags: python, time, win64, ctime

How do I sched a repeat timer for 5 min intervals. Which fire at 00 seconds, then repeat at 00. Ok, not hard real-time but as close as possible with sys lags. Trying to avoid a build up in lags and get near 00.

Lang: Python, OS: WinXP x64

System has 25ms resolution.

Any code would be helpful, tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do it any more accurately than with [threading.Timer](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects).  It's "one-shot", but that just means the function you schedule that way must immediately re-schedule itself for another 300 seconds later, first thing.  (You can add accuracy by measuring the exact time with `time.time` each time and varying the next scheduling delay accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Try and compare the time printouts of these two code samples:

**Code Sample 1**

```
import time
delay = 5

while True:
    now = time.time()
    print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(now))

    # As you will observe, this will take about 2 seconds,
    # making the loop iterate every 5 + 2 seconds or so.
    ## repeat 5000 times
    for i in range(5000):
        sum(range(10000))

    # This will sleep for 5 more seconds
    time.sleep(delay)
```

**Code Sample 2**

```
import time
delay = 5

while True:
    now = time.time()
    print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(now))

    # As you will observe, this will take about 2 seconds,
    # but the loop will iterate every 5 seconds because code 
    # execution time was accounted for.
    ## repeat 5000 times
    for i in range(5000):
        sum(range(10000))

    # This will sleep for as long as it takes to get to the
    # next 5-second mark
    time.sleep(delay - (time.time() - now))
```

Comment: Did you run the code? I modified my code samples so that you can see the time printouts. I used a 5-second delay to make it easier to demonstrate.

Comment: Trying it, TIA

How I kill it? 
How do get it to start at 00:05:00.0000?
How do check with microseconds. this is so I can see "below a second",

Comment: 2nd method worked better, TIA

Also, on win x64, see pthyonw.exe running, a couple of them, do know how to identify the correct Pythonw.exe to kill?

Comment: To see fractions of a second, add this line after `now = time.time()`: `print now`. To make it start at `5:00.0000`, do a `time.sleep(5*60)` right after `import time`. To identify the correct `pythonw.exe`, that would be a topic for another question. Cheers!

Comment: "To make it start at 5:00.0000, do a time.sleep(5*60) right after import time." didnt work....Idea now as float without fraction....

how do i kill this?