# Have python run script at X:00 am

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, time, solaris

Following up on,

[With python: intervals at x:00 repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553340/with-python-intervals-at-x00-repeat)

Using threading, How can I get a script to run starting at 8:00 am stop running at 5:00 pm

The solution should be coded within python, and be portable

tiA

Comment: Is this homework? If so, add the appropriate tag, please.

Comment: Its not homework, I have solution that work fine within SQL --trigger, now need python solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `time` module has a function called `asctime`, which might be useful for you:

```
>>> from time import asctime
>>> asctime()
'Tue Sep 21 17:49:42 2010'
```

So, you could incorporate something like the following into your code:

```
sysTime = asctime()
timestamp = systime.split()[3]
separator = timestamp[2]
hour = timestamp.split(separator)[0]
while hour < 8:
    # just wait
    sysTime = asctime()
    timestamp = systime.split()[3]
    separator = timestamp[2]
    hour = timestamp.split(separator)[0]

# now, it's just become 8:00 AM
while hour < 17: # until 5:00 PM
    sysTime = asctime()
    timestamp = systime.split()[3]
    separator = timestamp[2]
    hour = timestamp.split(separator)[0]

    # start your thread to do whatever needs to be done
```

Start this script off once and let it keep running forever.

This is in response to @user428862's question asking if this can be run with "hour > 8 and hour <17". This is how the code would need to be adapted for that purpose:

```
while 1:
    sysTime = asctime()
    timestamp = systime.split()[3]
    separator = timestamp[2]
    hour = timestamp.split(separator)[0]
    minute = timestamp.split(separator)[1]

    if (hour > 8) and (hour<17 and minute<1):
        # start your thread to do whatever needs to be done
```

Also , it just occurs to me that I have been imploying string splitting and that returns strings, so `hour` should be `int(timestamp.split(separator)[0])` and so forth

Comment: This is as portable as it gets, considering cron isn't an option for the OP.

Comment: same kind of logic in VBA and Sql, thx.  how often does the script run top to bottom. Would " hour > 8 and hour <17:" work? also, how would I modify for 8:30, if I need it.

Comment: with "(hour<17 and minute<1)", I can figure out...8:30 or 7:59 thanks again......

Answer (score 0):

in the cron, and you need to run script starting at 8:00 am stop running at 5:00 pm
use **crontab -e** command in linux .
and add this line code for

```
* 8 * * * /YOUR/PATH/SCRIPT
```

and you stop it in 5 pm, in this example we will kill all python process in 5 pm

```
* 17 * * * killall -9 /usr/bin/python
```

and you can check crontab with **crontab -l** and **crontab -r** for reset to default (no any command will be executed)